# Error appear while trying create new database play framework ebean mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, playframework, ebean

I have model orders and it gives me an error when I am trying to apply it:

> Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state! An evolution has not
>   been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it
>   manually before marking it as resolved.

While trying to run  SQL script below, we got the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'order ( id bigint auto_increment not null, description ' 
at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000], while trying to run this SQL script:
```

The script:

```
package models;

import play.data.format.Formats;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Order extends Model{

    @Id
    @Version
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;



    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    public String description;


    public  Boolean status;


    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date dueDate = new Date();

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date dueDate2 = new Date();


    public Double total;




    public Order(){
        //this.name=name;
        //.description=description;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, Order> find=new Finder<Long, Order>(Long.class, Order.class);


    public static List<Order> findAll() {
        return find.all();
    }


    public static void create(String name,String description){
        Order newMenu=new Order();
        newMenu.save();
    }

    public static void update(Long id,String name,String description){
        Order restaurant= Order.find.ref(id);
        System.out.println("id:"+id);
        //restaurant.name=name;
        /*restaurant.description=description;
        restaurant.update();*/


    }
    public static void delete(Long id){
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }
}
```

SQl:

```
# --- Rev:1,Ups - 50058ce

create table category (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
name                      varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
menu_id                   bigint,
parent_category           bigint,
constraint pk_category primary key (id))
;

create table menu (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
name                      varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
constraint pk_menu primary key (id))
;

create table menu_item (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
title                     varchar(255),
short_title               varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
price_original            integer,
price_for_sale            integer,
image                     varchar(255),
status                    tinyint(1) default 0,
cook_time                 integer,
prep_instruction          TEXT,
category_id               bigint,
unit                      ENUM('кг','л','штук'),
constraint ck_menu_item_unit check (unit in ('gramm','litr','item')),
constraint pk_menu_item primary key (id))
;

create table order (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
description               TEXT,
status                    tinyint(1) default 0,
due_date                  datetime,
due_date2                 datetime,
total                     double,
constraint pk_order primary key (id))
;

create table order_type (
id                        integer auto_increment not null,
title                     varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
status                    varchar(255),
constraint pk_order_type primary key (id))
;

create table restaurant (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
name                      varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
image                     varchar(255),
contact                   varchar(255),
address                   TEXT,
constraint pk_restaurant primary key (id))
;

create table restaurant_section (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
name                      varchar(255),
description               TEXT,
image                     varchar(255),
constraint pk_restaurant_section primary key (id))
;

create table smeny (
id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
name                      varchar(255),
opened                    TEXT,
closed                    TEXT,
constraint pk_smeny primary key (id))
;

create table user_test (
email                     varchar(40) not null,
password                  varchar(255),
name                      varchar(255),
role                      integer,
constraint pk_user_test primary key (email))
;

alter table category add constraint fk_category_menu_1 foreign key (menu_id) references menu (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_category_menu_1 on category (menu_id);
alter table category add constraint fk_category_parent_category_2 foreign key (parent_category) references category (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_category_parent_category_2 on category (parent_category);
alter table menu_item add constraint fk_menu_item_category_3 foreign key (category_id) references category (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_menu_item_category_3 on menu_item (category_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in MySQL [check](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). So you better change the name of your table.

Comment: Thanks!I have solve it! and change sql request and it works!

Comment: By the way do you know if my DATETIME realiztion is proper?